# Knife tool wont cut on face

Tags: modeling

I’m trying to use the knife tool, so I can make a cut/slice from vertex to vertex and sometimes I cannot make this happen.There is no Ngons so what am I not doing incorrect? or why is Blender not allowing this action to happen?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: this usually means there are duplicate vertices somewhere, or otherwise corrupted geometry. can you upload your blend file?

Comment: Hey :). Why not just press **J** to connect the vertices?

Comment: or that the destination vertex is part o a different face... again, invalid geometry... You can check using face selection mode.

Comment: Hi guys, for some reason the vertices were not connected.


Thank you.